# ¿Cómo podría recorrer un array de un archivo JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Quiero recorrerlo con un **bucle** for en JavaScript.

```js
let jsonObject =   {
        "hoteles": [{
            "viaje": {
                "origen": {
                    "iataCode": "VL",
                    "name": "Valencia",
                    
                },
                "destino": {
                    "iataCode": "BCN",
                    "name": "Barcelona",
                },
                "price": {
                    "value": "99.16",
                    "valueMainUnit": "99",
                    "valueFractionalUnit": "16",
                    "currencySymbol": "€"
                },
                "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
                "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
            }
        },
  {
            "viaje": {
                "origen": {
                    "iataCode": "VL",
                    "name": "madrid",
                    
                },
                "destino": {
                    "iataCode": "BCN",
                    "name": "Barcelona",
                },
                "price": {
                    "value": "99.16",
                    "valueMainUnit": "99",
                    "valueFractionalUnit": "16",
                    "currencySymbol": "€"
                },
                "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
                "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
            }
  }
  ]
 }


    for (var i=0; i< jsonObject.hoteles.length; i++)
    {
        //Para obtener el objeto de tu lista
        var hotel = jsonObject.hoteles[i]
        //Mostramos el objeto en su versión String
        console.log(JSON.stringify(hotel));
        //Muestras el valor de la propiedad name para el objeto viaje, del objeto hotel.
        document.write(console.log(hotel.viaje.origen.name));
    }
```

Al recorrerlo, ¿por qué me imprime dos veces ***`undefined`***? ¿Cómo podría recorrer este array?

Answer (score 3):

No tienes más que recorrer el array de la propiedad hoteles de tu objeto con un for:

```js
var jsonObject = {
    "hoteles": [{
        "viaje": {
            "origen": {
                "iataCode": "VL",
                "name": "Valencia",

            },
            "destino": {
                "iataCode": "BCN",
                "name": "Barcelona",
            },
            "price": {
                "value": "99.16",
                "valueMainUnit": "99",
                "valueFractionalUnit": "16",
                "currencySymbol": "€"
            },
            "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
            "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    },
    {
        "viaje": {
            "origen": {
                "iataCode": "VL",
                "name": "madrid",

            },
            "destino": {
                "iataCode": "BCN",
                "name": "Barcelona",
            },
            "price": {
                "value": "99.16",
                "valueMainUnit": "99",
                "valueFractionalUnit": "16",
                "currencySymbol": "€"
            },
            "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
            "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    }
    ]
};

for (var i=0; i< jsonObject.hoteles.length; i++){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject.hoteles[i]));
  console.log('origen viaje: ' + jsonObject.hoteles[i].viaje.origen.name);
}
```

Comment: vale, ahora quiero imprimir un dato, y los que hago es lo siguiente y me dice que el identificador es invalido. Como tendria que hacer?.                for (var i=0; i< jsonObject.hoteles.length; i++){
       for(var j=0;i<2;j++){
  document.write(console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject.hoteles[i].viaje[j].origen.name)));
 }
}

Comment: No trates de introducir código en los comentarios. Es mejor que edites y amplíes tu pregunta si se trata de completar la descripción del problema, o que crees una nueva pregunta si se trata de un problema diferente.

Comment: He editado la respuesta para incluir este punto.

Answer (score 3):

En relación al código que pusiste, podrías usar algo parecido a esto:

```
for (var i=0; i< jsonObject.hoteles.length; i++)
{
    //Para obtener el objeto de tu lista
    var hotel = jsonObject.hoteles[i];
    //Mostramos el objeto en su versión String
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hotel));
    //Muestras el valor de la propiedad name para el objeto viaje, del objeto hotel.
    console.log(hotel.viaje.origen.name)
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Comment: Porque razon me sale, undefined?

Comment: @gabrielgomez en que linea te da `undefined`

Comment: Creo que con el código que acabas de poner, sale "undefined" debido a que deseas recorrer el objeto JSON, pero al momento de hacerlo, este aún no se ha creado. debes añadir el código que puse, luego de haber definido el objeto JSON hoteles.

Comment: En la línea document.write que me comprometo el Name de cada viaje pero como si no tuviera valor

Comment: Es debido a que recorres el JSON y tratas de acceder a sus propiedades antes de declararlo.

Answer (score 2):

Te aparece *undefined* porque haces referencia a un atributo que no existe:

```
hotel.viaje.origen.name // no existe pues no se ha indicado el índice del arreglo hotel
```

Una forma en que puedes revisar tu arreglo podría ser así:

```
for (var i=0; i<jsonObject.hoteles.length; i++) {
  var hotel = jsonObject.hoteles[i]; // hasta aquí tienes cada hotel
  for (var detalle in hotel.viaje) {
    for (var dato in hotel.viaje[detalle]) {
       console.log (hotel.viaje[detalle][dato]); // Y aquí exploras cada dato del viaje
    }
  }
}
```

Puedes comprobarlo en este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtw5xo9x/10). Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

> Puedes usar el método Map para recorrerlo fácilmente y ahorrarte un
>   for

```
let hoteles = jsonObject.hoteles
hoteles.map((hotel) => { console.log(hotel) })
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos errores en el ejercicio

1. Debes declarar la variable y luego recorrer el **`for`**
2. la funcion [console.log](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) no retorna ningun valor! solo imprime valores.

> El `console.log` imprime los valores que esten dentro del parentesis, pero el no retorna ningun valor, por ende, al colocar `document.write(console.log("valor"))`; en realidad te esta imprimiendo el retorno de la funcion que es undefined

```js
function mantequilla(){
  console.log("chispas");
    return "chispas";
}
function mantequilla2(){
  
    return console.log("va a imprimir el valor pero retornara undefined");
}

document.write(mantequilla());

document.write(mantequilla2());
```

Como puedes observar en este ejemplo hice un console.log() pero no lo mostro ! en el html pues es el equivalente a lo que quieres hacer.

**Tu programación debe cambiar a algo asi:**

```js
let jsonObject = {
    "hoteles": [{
        "viaje": {
            "origen": {
                "iataCode": "VL",
                "name": "Valencia",

            },
            "destino": {
                "iataCode": "BCN",
                "name": "Barcelona",
            },
            "price": {
                "value": "99.16",
                "valueMainUnit": "99",
                "valueFractionalUnit": "16",
                "currencySymbol": "€"
            },
            "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
            "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    },
    {
        "viaje": {
            "origen": {
                "iataCode": "VL",
                "name": "madrid",

            },
            "destino": {
                "iataCode": "BCN",
                "name": "Barcelona",
            },
            "price": {
                "value": "99.16",
                "valueMainUnit": "99",
                "valueFractionalUnit": "16",
                "currencySymbol": "€"
            },
            "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
            "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    }
    ]
}
for (var i=0; i< jsonObject.hoteles.length; i++)
{
    //Para obtener el objeto de tu lista
    var hotel = jsonObject.hoteles[i]
    //Mostramos el objeto en su versión String
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hotel));
    //Muestras el valor de la propiedad name para el objeto viaje, del objeto hotel.
    document.write((hotel.viaje.origen.name));
}
```

Por favor no uses [document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2775976/5695795) para imprimir en la pagina

Answer (score 1):

Deberías asignar la información a una variable.

```
var variable = { // tus datos };

for(i = 0; i < variable.hoteles.length; i++){
   var datos = variable.hoteles[i].viaje;
   console.info(datos.origen);
   console.info(datos.destino);
   console.info(datos.precio);
}
```