# Navegar por un JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, json

Quiero tomar la información de este json (https://wotclans.com.br/api) y mostrarlos en un HTML y que me muestre solo los datos del equipo que tiene como clantag TRCIO, hasta ahora he conseguido que me muestre los datos, pero me muestra los de todos los equipos.
¿Cómo podría hacer para que me muestre solo los de ese en concreto?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    cargarDatos();
});
function cargarDatos() {
    var listaWot = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://wotclans.com.br/api',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'

    }).done(function (response) {
        listaWot = "";
        listaWot += "<div class='card-panel'>";
        listaWot += "<table>";
        listaWot += "<tr>";
        listaWot += "<td class='tabName'>";
        listaWot += "Posición";
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "<td class='tabName'>";
        listaWot += "Nombre";
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "<td class='tabName'>";
        listaWot += "Puntuación";
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "<td class='tabName'>";
        listaWot += "Ratio De Victorias";
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "<td class='tabName1'>";
        listaWot += "Miembros Activos";
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "</tr>";
        $.each(response.Clans, function (i, info) {
            listaWot += "<tr>";
            listaWot += "<td class='textCenter'>";
            listaWot += info.Item1;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "<td>";
            listaWot += info.Item2.Name;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "<td>";
            listaWot += info.Item2.TotalBattles;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "<td>";
            listaWot += info.Item2.TotalWinRate;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "<td class='textCenter'>";
            listaWot += info.Item2.Active;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "</tr>";
        });
        listaWot += "</table>";
        $("#wot").html(listaWot);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola Danny, por favor muéstranos el código que estás empleando para mostrar los datos y que es lo que quieres mostrar.

Comment: Acabo de editar el post, ese es el codigo que empleo, es un archivo js aparte y lo importo al html

Comment: Quizas esta esto te pueda ayudar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680768/export-to-xls-using-angularjs.
me lo he encontrado ya que estoy trabajando con graficacion de archivos Xls en graficos Chart.js

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como podría recorrer un array de un archivo json?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10969/como-podr%c3%ada-recorrer-un-array-de-un-archivo-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta parte del codigo estás atravesando todos los clanes mostrando la información:

```
    $.each(response.Clans, function (i, info) {
        listaWot += "<tr>";
        listaWot += "<td class='textCenter'>";
        listaWot += info.Item1;
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "<td>";
        listaWot += info.Item2.Name;
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "<td>";
        listaWot += info.Item2.TotalBattles;
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "<td>";
        listaWot += info.Item2.TotalWinRate;
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "<td class='textCenter'>";
        listaWot += info.Item2.Active;
        listaWot += "</td>";
        listaWot += "</tr>";
    });
```

Como no hay ningún tipo de restricción, se mostrará toda esa información de todos los clanes. Si lo que quieres es que sólo se muestre la información de los clanes TRCIO (el nombre se encuentra en `ClanTag`), lo único que tienes que hacer es añadir una comprobación para asegurarte que ese es el clan:

```
    $.each(response.Clans, function (i, info) {
        if (info.Item2.ClanTag == "TRCIO") {
            listaWot += "<tr>";
            listaWot += "<td class='textCenter'>";
            listaWot += info.Item1;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "<td>";
            listaWot += info.Item2.Name;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "<td>";
            listaWot += info.Item2.TotalBattles;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "<td>";
            listaWot += info.Item2.TotalWinRate;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "<td class='textCenter'>";
            listaWot += info.Item2.Active;
            listaWot += "</td>";
            listaWot += "</tr>";
        }
    });
```